# Tolerance of PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I believe the following should be `True` but returns `False` for me:

```
PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[DiagonalMatrix[{1, -10^-100}], Tolerance -> 10^-10]
```

As far as I can tell the `Tolerance` option does nothing. An easy workaround is

```
PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[A + tolerance*IdentityMatrix[Length@A]]
```

I have checked that this happens in 10.0.2 and 10.1. Is it still a bug in newer versions?

Comment: More generally, where can I find a list of fixed bugs between versions? I can only find lists of new features...

Comment: The `bugs` tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Once it is agreed that the behavior is actually a bug, a moderator (or someone of similar standing) will add the `bugs` tag.

Comment: "For **approximate** matrices, the option `Tolerance -> t` can be used..." per the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ.html).

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation:

> For **approximate** matrices, the option `Tolerance->t` can be used to indicate that all eigenvalues $\lambda$ satisfying $|\lambda|\leq t\lambda_{max}$ are taken to be zero where $\lambda_{max}$ is an eigenvalue largest in magnitude.

Note that you are providing an *exact* matrix, not an approximation. If you evaluate:

```
PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[DiagonalMatrix[{1, -10.^-100}]]
```

you get the result you expect, `True`. A decimal point, or the ` character can be used to denote that a value is approximate, or has some arbitrary precision.